# What is the encoding size of the average emoji emoticon?

Tags: memory, unicode

I sent my friend a text with a pizza slice emoji.  With tongue in cheek, he asked my how many bytes the slice was.  I would like to know the answer, but I'm struggling to find a detailed answer regarding the size individual emojis.

Here is a description of the [pizza slice emoji](https://www.emojibase.com/emoji/1f355/sliceofpizza) being used.

Comment: Not clear how this is a programming question. If you are asking about the encoding size, it depends on the encoding.

Comment: To add to that, enjoy yourself some Tom Scott explaining this to you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOcxwRc2Epg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your own link indicates that this is Unicode code point U+1F355, and that its appearance differs according to the client displaying it. Assuming the character is utf-8 encoded, that's 4 bytes: F0 9F 8D 95. Whatever you see on the receiving end is a locally stored bitmap, not something from the sender.

Comment: Note that code points in the supplementary planes (>= 0x10000) need 4 bytes in either UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32.